# MVC Passed List<T> from view to controller is NULL

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, null

please do you have any idea why my List is NULL after passing model from view.. I tried any solution i have found here and still nothing. List is a part of model class with another views.

**ModelView:**

```
public class PorizeniWzView
{
    public PorizeniWzDataView ProjectDataView { get; set; }
    public PorizeniWzSuppliersView SupplierView { get; set; }
    public PorizeniWzProjectStateView ProjectStateView { get; set; }
    public WzUberView WzUberView { get; set; }

    public PorizeniWzEventView CurrentEventView { get; set; }
    public PorizeniWzEventView NextEventView { get; set; }

    public PorizeniWzPatternsView PatternView { get; set; }
    public PorizeniWzPhasesView CurrentPhaseView { get; set; }


    public List<PorizeniWzEventView> ListOfProjectEvents { get; set; }
    public List<int> ListOfProjectEventInt { get; set; }
    public List<PorizeniWzProjectStateView> ListOfProjectStates { get; set; }
}
```

**View:**
In view i'm using foreach loop with index++. I have my own html helper for input with datetime. It works fine. In view i need set a date to BasicEvent, so i select only basic event from the list. It works.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("a1_FillUpEventsSave", "PorizeniWZ", FormMethod.Post, new { })){

@Html.RowText1For(m => m.ProjectDataView.Project_Id, READ_ONLY, DEBUG)

int[] index = {-1};
foreach (var ev in listOfEvents)
{
    if (!ev.BasicEvent.HasValue || ev.BasicEvent == false) {
        index[0]++; continue;
    }
    index[0]++;
    <div class="row" style="margin-top: 15px;">

        <div title='Klíčová událost' class='btn btn-xs'>
            <div class='glyphicons glyphicons-keys'></div>
        </div>
        <b style="font-size: 17px">@ev.EventTypeNameCz</b> &nbsp;&nbsp; <span class="btn btn-xs" title="@ev.PhaseName" style="background-color: @ev.PhaseWebColor"><span class="@ev.PhaseWebIcon" style="color: white"></span></span>

        @Html.RowText1For(m => m.ListOfProjectEvents[index[0]].Event_Id, READ_ONLY, DEBUG)
        @Html.RowDate1For(m => m.ListOfProjectEvents[index[0]].DatePlanned, view)
    </div>      }
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 text-center" style="margin-top: 30px;">
        <input type="submit" value="Potvrdit termíny u klíčových událostí" class="btn btn-success" style="width: 400px; font-weight: bold" />
    </div>
</div>}
```

**Controller:**
There is a method GetFullView(id). This method fill up view with information from the database. List of ProjectEvents is there initialized.

```
       public ActionResult a1_CreateFillUpEvents(int id)
    {
        var view = _repo.GetFullView(id);
        if (view == null) KontrolaHelp.Error("Projekt pořízení WZ nenalezen!");

        return View("CreateFillUpEvents", view);
    }
```

Controller(Save form): Here I upadate events in the databese

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult a1_FillUpEventsSave(PorizeniWzView view)
    {
        if(!ModelState.IsValid) KontrolaHelp.ErrorModel(ModelState);
        var t = _repo.GetPodlePK(view.ProjectDataView.Project_Id);            
        if (t == null) KontrolaHelp.Error("Chyba DB. Projekt pořízení WZ nenalezen!");
        using (var transakce = _jednotka.Transakce_New())
        {
            foreach (var ev in view.ListOfProjectEvents)
            {
                if (ev.BasicEvent.HasValue && ev.BasicEvent.Value)
                {
                    var e = t?.Events1.Single(x => x.Event_Id == ev.Event_Id);
                    if (e == null) continue;
                    e.DatePlanned = ev.DatePlanned;
                    _repoEvents.Update(e);
                }
            }

            t.ProjectState_Id = (int) PorizeniWzSTAV.a17_Nastaveny;
            _repo.Update(t);
            transakce.Commit();
        }

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

Method for INIT List of Events

```
        public List<PorizeniWzEventView> GetEventsForProject(int? id)
    {
        var repoEventTypes = new TabPorizeniWzEventsTypesRepo(_jednotkaPrace);
        var set = GetSet().Where(t => t.ProjectId == id).OrderBy(t => t.Order);
        var list = set.ToList();
        foreach (var porizeniWzEventView in list){
            porizeniWzEventView.ListOfStates = repoEventTypes.DoplnStavyProTypUdalosti(porizeniWzEventView.EventTypeId);
        }
        return set.ToList();
    }
```

Comment: Which one of the three lists?

Comment: Do you try to create those lists anywhere? Just defining them in a model does not create them so based on your code they are Always null because they are never created.

Comment: Please include the code from the `Action` in the `Controller`. The bug is there.

Comment: You haven't initialized your list anywhere...
You can make a method in your viewModel where you init a list and then set it to the property. This method you can then invoke from your controller.

Comment: Thanks for help.. It is ListOfProjectEvents. And I init list in Controller when go to view. In view i see items in List, but when i pass Model back to controller its NULL.

Comment: `view.ListOfProjectEvents = _repoEvents.GetEventsForProject(id)`

Comment: Please use Chrome Developer Tools to get the payload being posted to `a1_FillUpEventsSave` and share it here.

Comment: This is data what i get. I can access it from FormCollection. ProjectDataView.Project_Id:"1002" , ListOfProjectEvents[1].Event_Id:"1003" , ListOfProjectEvents[1].DatePlanned:"01.10.2017", ListOfProjectEvents[4].Event_Id:"1006", ListOfProjectEvents[4].DatePlanned:"02.10.2017"

Comment: Do you want to see any headers which would help you? Again thanks for tring to help

Comment: When i change @Html helpers to `@Html.RowText1For(m => m.ListOfProjectEvents[0].Event_Id, READ_ONLY, DEBUG)
            @Html.RowDate1For(m => m.ListOfProjectEvents[0].DatePlanned, view)` It's mean set instad of i some number. Then List is not null anymore :/ Any tips ?

Comment: PROBLEM SOLVED!! You cant skip index in `m => m.ListOfProjectEvents[0].DatePlanned` It has to be like 0,1,2,3 becouse of my skipping it was like 0,4,8,12 and List was null after passing